# How to handle MySQL locks?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, phpmyadmin

My requirement is, users can click and avail the deal.
One deal can be availed by only one member, so I'm locking the table when a user tries to avail a deal, and unlocking it.  So that if two users clicks and tries to avail the deal, it will form a queue and it will prevent two users to avail the deal.

The code is like

```
LOCK TABLES deal WRITE;
//MySQL queries and my php code goes here.
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The problem now is, what if some problem happens with my php code between lock and unlock,
will the table get locked permanently? Is there anyway i can set a maximum time to lock the table?

Comment: I suggest you [start reading here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) - this contains the answers to your questions

Answer (score 0):

If I would have been in your place I would have created a database table named locked_deals. It would have a column named deal_id. When ever a user chooses a deal, its deal_id will get inserted into the locked_deals table. And when the next user clicks on the same deal it will first check if the deal_id is in lock table. If yes it would not allow the user to choose the deal. Finally when everything goes fine we can delete the lock_id from the lock table at the end of process. For the lock_ids which get stuck into the table because of any exception in the php code - we can create a background service that cleans the stucked ids (which ahve been stuck for the last n minutes) in the locked_deals table every n minutes.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This wont work: a process could add lock_id in the table just after another one checked the table and did not find lock_id. In this case, the second process would then also add lock_id to the table. Here we really need native MySQL locks.

Comment: @Aurel By making lock_id the Primary Key we can make sure that no two users/process can add the same deal_id into the table. This whole process of adding/deleting deal_id into/from the lock_ids table will be done through a stored proc and any primary key violation can easily be handled thus making sure that only 1 user/process gets a lock on a particular deal.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the session.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)